# Pass Git SHA1 commit id for next build(s) in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Consider a stream of jobs: A - B - C

I can parameterize to build B with the same git commit SHA1 as A by adding "Pass-through Git commit that was build" parameter in A. However, this only works for subsequent jobs.

Now, let's say that

A uses the project http://www.github.com/myuser/project_A

B uses the project http://www.github.com/myuser/project_B

C uses the project http://www.github.com/myuser/project_A

So what I want to do is to build C with the same SHA1 used in A.

The only way I found is to pass the SHA1 from A to B as parameter with a different name

```
GIT_MY_PARAMETER=$GIT_COMMIT
```

Then pass tis parameter from B to C

```
GIT_MY_PARAMETER =$GIT_MY_PARAMETER
```

Then in C I configured the git in this way:

```
Branches to build    Branch Specifier (blank for 'any')   ${GIT_MY_PARAMETER}
```

It works but I have the impression that it's not the perfect solution.

Is there a proper approach using the git plugin?

Comment: As of version 1.1.5 the Jenkins Git plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) has added an extension of the Parameterized Trigger Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to allow Git SHA1 of the current build to be passed to downstream builds. Does this solve your issue?

Comment: well no, it does not solve my problem because, like I said, the Git Parameterized Trigger Plugin works only with subsequent jobs building from the same repo.

Comment: I like your solutions with passing parameters. Parameters is default way how pipeline is built and makes build explicit.

Comment: I think this is reasonable solution...just wondering how it really works -so you are not using "Pass-through Git commit that was build", right?      One difference between that and the workaround is: the former works also when you manually kick off the build (taking the latest, say, "master").. ah or you can actually setting GIT_MY_PARAMETER to the master as default..?